# Android com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress DonutProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor(int color) not working?

Tags: java, android, android-library

I'm using this library : https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress for my UI.

I'd like to know if it's possible to change the finished_color programatically. I'm having trouble doing it :

Using `donutProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor(R.color.orange);` or whatever color won't do anything, instead it puts a blue/purple color as you can see below :

[image: UI - DonutProgress]

Am I using this method the right way/the good method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using :

`donutProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor(Color.parseColor("#color_code"));`

It seems like the method can't manage to use resource colors such as R.color.mycolor.